# Show white space before loading pictures

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I am busy creating a customized carousel using Twitter Bootstrap.  To see what I've got so far, see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/narfie/20u6dq9o/).

My problem is when it first loads, and there's data underneath the carousel, the div is empty, and the data then gets "pushed" down as soon as the first picture loads.  This is very ugly.

I don't explicitly want to specify a height for my carousel, because I want it to resize on different devices.

Should I maybe use explicit sizes for different media types like so?

```
@media(max-width:767px){
  #carousel {
    height:100px;
  }
}
@media(min-width:768px){}
@media(min-width:992px){}
@media(min-width:1200px){
  #carousel {
    height:380px;
  }
}
```

I'm not sure how to use the media queries work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you know the aspect ratio of your carousel, you can use the "padding-bottom" hack to keep the carousel's size constant without specifying the height to keep things responsive:

```
#carousel {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.2%; // 16:9 for example
    height: 0;
}
#carousel > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

Google finds a lot for "responsive embedding" and "padding-bottom hack". Originally got used for responsive video embeds.

Comment: aaaaand that's why I hang out here :D.  Thanx dude!  What a simple solution.

Comment: you are welcome. You might wanna change `> div` to the real inner wrapper though.

Answer (score 1):

You are close, it's

```
@media screen and (max-width:767px){
  #carousel {
    height:100px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px and max-width:992px){

}

@media screen and (min-width:993px and max-width:1191px){

}

@media screen and (min-width:1200px){
    #carousel {
        height:380px;
      }
}
```

And you add your rules inside the media queries

Comment: Thanx, singe31. I now understand how to use the media queries, but I have opted for Marc's solution as the answer for this one.